# Add Parameter to Laravel Eloquent relationship in "with" function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to add a parameter to my Eloquent relationship in the `with::` static method.

I have a Dealer Model that has those relationships

```
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'dealer_id', 'dealer_id');
    }

    public function recentEvents($interval = 14)
    {
        return $this->events()
            ->whereDate('datestart', '>=', Carbon::now('America/Toronto')->subDays($interval))
            ->whereDate('dateend', '>=', Carbon::now('America/Toronto'));
    }
```

Everything works fine if I call it like this `$dealer->recentEvents(20)` but in my `DealerController` 
I would like to do something in the line of this

```
Dealer::with("recentEvents")
                ->where('dealer_flag', 1)
                ->orderBy('dealer_storename', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

Where i would pass a paremeter to "recentEvents".

I've tried putting a closure function to `with` like this

```
Dealer::with(["recentEvents" => function ($query) use ($interval){ 
 //The problem here is that I would need to put the recent-events code like this
$query->whereDate('cal_datestart', '>=', Carbon::now('America/Toronto')->subDays($interval))
            ->whereDate('cal_dateend', '>=', Carbon::now('America/Toronto'));
}])
                ->where('dealer_flag', 1)
                ->orderBy('dealer_storename', 'ASC')
                ->get();
```

But it would defeat the purpose of having a `recentEvents` relationship.
Is it possible to just pass a parameter ?

I've tried using Dynamic Scope from Laravel doc but I figured it was not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should use like this

```php
Dealer::with(["events",function($q) use($interval){
                $q->whereDate('datestart', '>=', Carbon::now('America/Toronto')->subDays($interval))
                ->whereDate('dateend', '>=', Carbon::now('America/Toronto'));
            }])
            ->where('dealer_flag', 1)
            ->orderBy('dealer_storename', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Seems like a viable solution but if a solution without repeating the code exist, it would be even better